# Exponential growth of input range values

Tags: html, html-input

When you use a HTML input element for defining a range, like this one:

`<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="100" name="distance"/>`

Is it possible to have the values grow exponentially? Such as that, if you slide just a tad near the left-hand side, it will make a difference from 1 to 2 (miles of distance for example), but if you slide it by the same amount on the right-hand side, it will make the difference from 900 and 1000 miles.

You know what I mean? Because it's not fair that the middle is 500, and then you can never ever fine-tune it to something like 20 or 40, but on the other hand if you go high up it makes less and less diffence to fine-tune it to 820 or 840.

I hope my question is clear. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Is it possible* yes. Is it possible to do with pure HTML: No.

Answer (score 2):

HMTL

```
<input id="distanceRange" type="range" name="distance" min="0" max="100" value="0">
```

`<output id="distanceOutput">1</output>`

javascript

```
document.getElementById("distanceRange").oninput = function(){
  document.getElementById("distanceOutput").value = Math.round(Math.exp((Math.log(1000)/100) * document.getElementById("distanceRange").value));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to "input" event of this range, get the value and calculate the exponential with javascript. You can set the value range as 0..100 to ease things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML range input has a constant `step`(default step is 1), the variation is linear.

If you want other variation method like 2 to the nth power, octave or fibonacci, you may change `step` dynamically, but the default draging behaviour of browser may not support you to do so.

Or you may use various elements together to finish the task:

- `<input type="range">` to control the factor of current value
- `<datalist>` to show ruler for the factor slider
- `<meter>` to visualize current value
- `<output>` to show current value as text

Taking FFT Size as an example:

[fftSize](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/fftSize) must be a power of 2 between `2^5` and `2^15` (32 ~ 32768), default is 2048

```js
let $ = (s, c = document) => c.querySelector(s);

function main(){
  let input = $('input[name="fftSizeFactor"]');
  let meter =  $('meter[name="fftSize"]');
  let output = $('output[name="fftSize"]');

  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    // regard the factor as exponent of current value
    let exponent = e.target.value;
    output.value = meter.value = Math.pow(2, exponent);
  });
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    console.debug('fftSize changed to', output.value);
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

```css
input[name="fftSizeFactor"]{
  width: 60px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
meter[name="fftSize"]{
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Exponential Slider Example</h3>

<div>
  fftSize:
  <input type="range" name="fftSizeFactor" min="5" max="15" value="11"
      list="fftSizeList" autocomplete="off" />
  <meter name="fftSize" min="32" max="32768" value="2048"></meter>
  <output name="fftSize">2048</output>
  <datalist id="fftSizeList">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
  </datalist>
</div>
```